# Multiple VPN Server form a single local network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn

**Present Status**: 
I have a openVPN server hosted on AWS and nearly 50 client computers connected to the VPN. So as of now, all the client are on same network

**Problem with the current setup**: 
If I ever do any server update/development, all my clients are disconnected or vulnerable to server breakdown. Besides, in future my server machine may crash and this may lead to all clients being disconnected.

**What I want to achieve**: 
I want to setup 2 openVPN server on AWS. so that typically 25 clients connect to server1 and rest 25 connect to server 25. If I ever take server1 down, all the clients connect to server2 and vice versa. I believe this is easy to achieve.

I want that both the two VPN server form a single local network. So if Client1 is connected to Server1 and Client47 is connected to Server2, both Client1 and Client47 should be part of single local network.

I want this so that irrespective of the VPN server the developer is connected to(if developer is connected to server1), he should be able to connected to client on server2( as if they are in same local network).
Something like masking local IP address, so that clients on server1 are 10.8.[0-127].xxx and on server2 are 10.8.[128-255].xxx

**Possible approaches**: 
Server2 can be a client of server1, but still they will not form a local network. Server1 and Server2 can continuously share data and updates, however still it will not form a local network.

What is an effective and best solution for this?

Comment: This looks like exactly what you are looking for: https://serverfault.com/questions/908239/openvpn-ha-setup-on-aws